# CSS not Parsing

Tags: html, css

So I am not entirely sure what exactly is happening here. I am fairly certain that all of my coding is correct, but for some reason it is not displaying properly on the web page. Here is a list of my code, and even a screen shot of what is happening. Google Chrome even shows that it received the code, but it is clearly not displaying.

HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Add Artec Racer</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
   </head>
   <body>

     <div class="main">
       <h1>Some Information</h1>
     </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

CSS:

```
    body
    {
      color: #000000;
    }

   body div.main
   {
     color: #202020;
     width: 1000px;
     margin: auto;
   }
```

Any help would be fantastic, but here is the picture for what I am seeing. I am running Linux Mint, Apache 2, MySQL, and PHP5. I restarted Apache with no change in result. Here is what I am seeing:

http://i169.photobucket.com/albums/u209/eowdaemon/ChromeIssue.png

Comment: What is incorrect about how it's displaying?

Comment: **Things to try:** Remove `color` from `body` class.  Add `div.main h1` class and specify `color` there.  Add `!important` to `color: #202020`.

Comment: Check development tool in Chrome and have a look on network activity, does it correctly download the css file?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jnnpq/ Works for me. Perhaps you're not loading your CSS file correctly? Check your file tree.

Comment: The picture you provided looks like what the fiddle is producing. What should it look like?

Comment: use `<link href="../css/main.css">` and not `./css/main.css`

Comment: Try to use root-relative paths whenever you can. Start with a slash.

Comment: Try changing `body div.main{ color:` to something like `#FF0000` so you can tell if it's working. It looks fine to me.

Comment: Are you confusing background-color with color?  What you are showing is working.

Comment: iamnotmaynard: the background color is black, not white, and the div information is not applying at all. Thus the screenshot. The information is being parsed by Chrome, it shows the color it is supposed to be, but it is not actually that color...

Comment: Thanks Jason, it was just that simple. Background-color instead of color. I feel pretty stupid right now. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot you posted looks exactly like what your CSS should be producing.

If you're intending to have centered text, try adding `text-align: center;` to your `body` rule.

If that's not your intent, it's possible you're confusing `color` with `background-color`.
`color` changes text, while `background-color` changes the color of the background.

Comment: It was mixing up color with background-color. It has been a long day X(

Answer (score 0):

When you go to access your css file, it should be ../ not ./

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
/*in the href, it should be:*/
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
```

Comment: Articulous, I am not jumping back a directory, I am opening a directory in the current folder. I just mixed up background-color with color.